# What does "can freeze hell over with a glance" mean?

Tags: idioms, american-english, spoken-english

I read on a post, "The kindest people alive but can freeze hell over with a glance" squad. Is it a kind of English idioms. What does it mean?

Comment: Is the source something related to Astrology and Horoscope ?

Comment: It is related to Horoscope.

Answer (score 2):

I've dug over the internet and I've found out that

> **"The kindest people alive but can freeze hell over with a glance" squad.**

is something that is used to describe the group of people who are born under the zodiac signs of **Aquarius, Virgo, Gemini, Taurus, Cancer**. 
The sentence tries to sum up the characteristics of this group of people using a single sentence. So what does it mean ?

People born under the signs of Aquarius, Virgo, Gemini, Taurus, Cancer are very kind people, perhaps the kindest people among all their counterpart in the other zodiac signs. Even with such a warm-heart, they can become cold and heartless, when  circumstances force them to be. This is symbolic, rather than idiomatic. Hell is always referred to as the hottest place (with all the fires, or so they say). Now to freeze hell is a herculean task (hypothetically). If someone can be as cold as that, it means that they can become very heartless, given the unfavorable situations. So in plain words, these people are generally very nice and warm-hearted, but can become cold and heartless when they are angry or annoyed or sad.

**NOTE**:
As far as idioms go, [when Hell freezes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/when_Hell_freezes_over) is an idiom used to describe something that is highly unlikely to happen. But I don't think that has to do anything with the phrase used in your context.

Answer (score 2):

Your sentence

> **The kindest people alive but can freeze hell over with a glance**

is describing a group of people as having a **warm and generous nature**

> The **kindest** *(possible)* **people alive**

but also potentially very **emotionally cold** *(hearted)*, since they can

> **freeze hell over**

**Hell** is thought of as being the **hottest** possible place in human imagination.
To **freeze** it, something would need to be **very cold**, and to freeze it

> **with** *(just)* **a glance**

something would need to be **extraordinarily cold** since **a glance** is an **infinitesimally small** period of time.  Think **Elsa** in *Frozen*.  It also has the connotation that the emotion from **hot to cold** can happen fairly **quickly**.

The idiom in your sentence is

> *(with)* **at a glance**

meaning very quickly.